# Missing environment variables when using webpack to build Node.js application

Tags: node.js, webpack, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm using the dot-env and envalid NPM package to pass variables from .env to Node/express application.

This is working perfectly well in development.

But when I use webpack to build the application bundle for PRODUCTION mode, all the variables from .env become undefined.

Any advise on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const DotenvWebpackPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');

const serverConfig = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production',
  entry: './src/server.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          configFile: 'tsconfig.json',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new DotenvWebpackPlugin({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env'),
      safe: false,
      systemvars: true,
    }),
  ],
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};

module.exports = [serverConfig];
```

**.env**

```
NODE_ENV=production

SERVER_PORT=3000
SERVER_SECRET=foo
```

**envalidUtil.ts**

```
import { cleanEnv } from 'envalid';
import { port, str, num } from 'envalid/dist/validators';

export default cleanEnv(process.env, {
  SERVER_PORT: num(),
  SERVER_SECRET: str(),
});
```

**Usage:**

```
import 'dotenv/config'; 
import env from './envalidUtil';

const port = env.SERVER_PORT || 5000;
console.log(port)
console.log(SERVER_SECRET)
```

Output:

```
Missing environment variables:
SERVER_PORT: undefined
SERVER_SECRET: undefined
```